# The matrix $J$(all of whose entries are 1) is a polynomial in the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph $G$ ...

Tags: graph-theory

if and only if $G$ is connected and regular.

To prove the "only if", assume $J$ is a polynomial in $A$. Then $JA=AJ$. The entries in the $i$th row of $AJ$ are all equal to the sum of the entries in the $i$th row of $A$. The entries in the $i$th column of $JA$ are all equal to the sum of the entries in the $i$th column of $A$. Therefore, the sums of entries in a row of $A$ is constant. This shows that $G$ is regular. Also $G$ must be connected, for otherwise $i$ and $j$ is not connected and the $ij$th entry of $A^n$ is always zero and $J$ cannot be a polynomial in $A$.

But how can I show the other implication?

Comment: If $J$ is a polynomial in $A$ then $AJ=JA$. All entries in a row of $AJ$ are equal,...

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question according to your hint. Though I still need to prove the other implication.

Comment: For the other direction I would use spectral decomposition, and the fact that the degree is a simple eigenvalue of $A$. (Sorry to be cryptic but I am short of time right now.) I think this is all proved in Biggs "Algebraic Graph Theory".

Comment: Let $B$ be a random real $n\times n$ matrix and $K=\sum_k c_k B^k$ be a polynomial, then $BK=KB$, because $[B^k,B]=0$. But $B$ is not regular. Where is the difference to your setup?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be regular and connected with adjacency matrix $A$. Using regularity and connectedness, $d:=deg(G)$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenspace spanned by $(1,\dots,1)$.

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Since $A$ is diagonable it splits as linear factors with $(x-d)$ being one of them. Say $m(x) = (x-d)p(x)$.

This relation seen in the matrix algebra gives 
$$0 = (A-d.I)p(A).
$$

Now $p(A)$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the one dimensional subspace $\operatorname{Ker}(A-d.I)$. Moreover $p(A)$ is not the zero-operator (by considerations on the minimal polynomial).

Thus $p(A)$ is a rank one, $\textit{symmetric}$ matrix with at least one column being a non-zero scalar multiple of $(1,\dots,1)$. This gives the result?